# Suddenly error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)

Tags: linux, debian, java

So this morning I noticed my website is down, went on my server and saw that the webserver has been stopped.

When I try to start it again I get this error

```
 start -Dhttp.port=80 -Dapplication.secret=**********
[info] Wrote /home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/scala-2.11/botlanegg_2.11-1.0.pom

(Starting server. Type Ctrl+D to exit logs, the server will remain in background)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000d5550000, 715849728, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 715849728 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/hs_err_pid3892.log
```

What is confusing me is that yesterday the webserver ran without problems, and suddenly this morning it is down? Debian 7.8 is runnin on the server.

cat /proc/meminfo shows

```
 MemTotal:        1027040 kB
MemFree:          626340 kB
Buffers:           16304 kB
Cached:           233932 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           249580 kB
Inactive:         121680 kB
Active(anon):     121076 kB
Inactive(anon):      164 kB
Active(file):     128504 kB
Inactive(file):   121516 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                48 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        121056 kB
Mapped:            21108 kB
Shmem:               216 kB
Slab:              17412 kB
SReclaimable:      10892 kB
SUnreclaim:         6520 kB
KernelStack:        1168 kB
PageTables:         2704 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      513520 kB
Committed_AS:     438980 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:        4972 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359733071 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       30708 kB
DirectMap2M:     1017856 kB
```

It seems that suddenly I don't have enough memory right? I really don`t know what to do, to make it work again, hopefully someone can help me out.

Here the full error log file:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 715849728 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2671), pid=3139, tid=140373617166080
#
# JRE version:  (8.0_31-b13) (build )
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.31-b07 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000001cfa000):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=3194, stack(0x00007fab47864000,0x00007fab47965000)]

Stack: [0x00007fab47864000,0x00007fab47965000],  sp=0x00007fab47963390,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0xa79e0a]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x2ca
V  [libjvm.so+0x4e57bb]  report_vm_out_of_memory(char const*, int, unsigned long, VMErrorType, char const*)+0x8b
V  [libjvm.so+0x8e5a23]  os::Linux::commit_memory_impl(char*, unsigned long, bool)+0x103
V  [libjvm.so+0x8e5f79]  os::pd_commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool)+0x29
V  [libjvm.so+0x8dfc4a]  os::commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool)+0x2a
V  [libjvm.so+0xa75d39]  VirtualSpace::expand_by(unsigned long, bool)+0x1c9
V  [libjvm.so+0xa768ce]  VirtualSpace::initialize(ReservedSpace, unsigned long)+0xee
V  [libjvm.so+0x5d2e21]  CardGeneration::CardGeneration(ReservedSpace, unsigned long, int, GenRemSet*)+0xf1
V  [libjvm.so+0xa209bc]  TenuredGeneration::TenuredGeneration(ReservedSpace, unsigned long, int, GenRemSet*)+0x5c
V  [libjvm.so+0x5d409b]  GenerationSpec::init(ReservedSpace, int, GenRemSet*)+0x33b
V  [libjvm.so+0x5c2bee]  GenCollectedHeap::initialize()+0x1ee
V  [libjvm.so+0xa45d4d]  Universe::initialize_heap()+0xfd
V  [libjvm.so+0xa4616f]  universe_init()+0x3f
V  [libjvm.so+0x6128d5]  init_globals()+0x65
V  [libjvm.so+0xa2bdbd]  Threads::create_vm(JavaVMInitArgs*, bool*)+0x24d
V  [libjvm.so+0x6a9b34]  JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x74
C  [libjli.so+0x736e]  JavaMain+0x9e
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x6b50]  start_thread+0xd0


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

=>0x0000000001cfa000 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=3194, stack(0x00007fab47864000,0x00007fab47965000)]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (0 events):
No events


Dynamic libraries:
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 884862                             /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 fe:02 884862                             /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java
01cea000-01d2c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
c0000000-d5550000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fab3c47e000-7fab3c79f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fab3c79f000-7fab3c8f4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fab3c8f4000-7fab3c8ff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fab3c8ff000-7fab3caf5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fab3caf5000-7fab3cd65000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fab3cd65000-7fab44af5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fab44af5000-7fab44b0f000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 901189                     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7fab44b0f000-7fab44d0f000 ---p 0001a000 fe:02 901189                     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7fab44d0f000-7fab44d10000 rw-p 0001a000 fe:02 901189                     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7fab44d10000-7fab44d1b000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 510300                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
7fab44d1b000-7fab44f1a000 ---p 0000b000 fe:02 510300                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
7fab44f1a000-7fab44f1b000 r--p 0000a000 fe:02 510300                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
7fab44f1b000-7fab44f1c000 rw-p 0000b000 fe:02 510300                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
7fab44f1c000-7fab44f26000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 510330                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
7fab44f26000-7fab45125000 ---p 0000a000 fe:02 510330                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
7fab45125000-7fab45126000 r--p 00009000 fe:02 510330                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
7fab45126000-7fab45127000 rw-p 0000a000 fe:02 510330                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
7fab45127000-7fab4513c000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 510320                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
7fab4513c000-7fab4533b000 ---p 00015000 fe:02 510320                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
7fab4533b000-7fab4533c000 r--p 00014000 fe:02 510320                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
7fab4533c000-7fab4533d000 rw-p 00015000 fe:02 510320                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
7fab4533d000-7fab4533f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fab4533f000-7fab45346000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 510361                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
7fab45346000-7fab45545000 ---p 00007000 fe:02 510361                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
7fab45545000-7fab45546000 r--p 00006000 fe:02 510361                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
7fab45546000-7fab45547000 rw-p 00007000 fe:02 510361                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
7fab45547000-7fab45571000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 901184                     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7fab45571000-7fab45771000 ---p 0002a000 fe:02 901184                     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7fab45771000-7fab45773000 rw-p 0002a000 fe:02 901184                     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7fab45773000-7fab45780000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 901188                     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7fab45780000-7fab45980000 ---p 0000d000 fe:02 901188                     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7fab45980000-7fab45982000 rw-p 0000d000 fe:02 901188                     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7fab45982000-7fab45989000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 510380                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
7fab45989000-7fab45b88000 ---p 00007000 fe:02 510380                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
7fab45b88000-7fab45b89000 r--p 00006000 fe:02 510380                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
7fab45b89000-7fab45b8a000 rw-p 00007000 fe:02 510380                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
7fab45b8a000-7fab45c0b000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 510365                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7fab45c0b000-7fab45e0a000 ---p 00081000 fe:02 510365                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7fab45e0a000-7fab45e0b000 r--p 00080000 fe:02 510365                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7fab45e0b000-7fab45e0c000 rw-p 00081000 fe:02 510365                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7fab45e0c000-7fab46a7a000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 901174                     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7fab46a7a000-7fab46c79000 ---p 00c6e000 fe:02 901174                     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7fab46c79000-7fab46d4f000 rw-p 00c6d000 fe:02 901174                     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7fab46d4f000-7fab46d92000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fab46d92000-7fab46f14000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 510355                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7fab46f14000-7fab47114000 ---p 00182000 fe:02 510355                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7fab47114000-7fab47118000 r--p 00182000 fe:02 510355                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7fab47118000-7fab47119000 rw-p 00186000 fe:02 510355                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7fab47119000-7fab4711e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fab4711e000-7fab47120000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 510423                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7fab47120000-7fab47320000 ---p 00002000 fe:02 510423                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7fab47320000-7fab47321000 r--p 00002000 fe:02 510423                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7fab47321000-7fab47322000 rw-p 00003000 fe:02 510423                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7fab47322000-7fab47337000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 892931                     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7fab47337000-7fab47536000 ---p 00015000 fe:02 892931                     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7fab47536000-7fab47537000 rw-p 00014000 fe:02 892931                     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7fab47537000-7fab4754e000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 510416                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
7fab4754e000-7fab4774d000 ---p 00017000 fe:02 510416                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
7fab4774d000-7fab4774e000 r--p 00016000 fe:02 510416                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
7fab4774e000-7fab4774f000 rw-p 00017000 fe:02 510416                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
7fab4774f000-7fab47753000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fab47753000-7fab47773000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 510324                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7fab4785c000-7fab47864000 rw-s 00000000 fe:02 655376                     /tmp/hsperfdata_root/3139
7fab47864000-7fab47867000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fab47867000-7fab47969000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fab4796b000-7fab4796f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fab4796f000-7fab47970000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fab47970000-7fab47972000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fab47972000-7fab47973000 r--p 0001f000 fe:02 510324                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7fab47973000-7fab47974000 rw-p 00020000 fe:02 510324                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7fab47974000-7fab47975000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff37ee7000-7fff37f0a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff37fff000-7fff38000000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m -Duser.dir=/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage -Dhttp.port=80 -Dapplication.secret=8a7s9df7as9d -Dhttp.port=80 
java_command: play.core.server.NettyServer
java_class_path (initial): /home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/botlanegg.botlanegg-1.0.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.1.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/com.typesafe.play.twirl-api_2.11-1.0.2.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/org.apache.commons.commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/org.scala-lang.modules.scala-xml_2.11-1.0.1.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/com.typesafe.play.build-link-2.3.7.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/com.typesafe.play.play-exceptions-2.3.7.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/org.javassist.javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.7.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/org.scala-stm.scala-stm_2.11-0.7.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/com.typesafe.config-1.2.1.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/com.typesafe.play.play-json_2.11-2.3.7.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/com.typesafe.play.play-functional_2.11-2.3.7.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/com.typesafe.play.play-datacommons_2.11-2.3.7.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/joda-time.joda-time-2.3.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/org.joda.joda-convert-1.6.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations-2.3.2.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.3.2.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar:/home/Jakob/Apps/Botlanegg/target/universal/stage/lib/or
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0xa7a650], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0xa7a650], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x8e28f0], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x8e28f0], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x8e28f0], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x8e28f0], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x8e4120], sa_mask[0]=00100000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGHUP: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGINT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGTERM: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGQUIT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.debian.org/"

uname:Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u1 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.13 NPTL 2.13 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 7919, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
load average:0.32 0.08 0.03

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:        1027040 kB
MemFree:          224852 kB
Buffers:           13844 kB
Cached:           211228 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           615288 kB
Inactive:         154744 kB
Active(anon):     545032 kB
Inactive(anon):      244 kB
Active(file):      70256 kB
Inactive(file):   154500 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:               836 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        545016 kB
Mapped:            46884 kB
Shmem:               292 kB
Slab:              17012 kB
SReclaimable:       9844 kB
SUnreclaim:         7168 kB
KernelStack:        1464 kB
PageTables:         5752 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      513520 kB
Committed_AS:    2056244 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:        4972 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359733071 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       30708 kB
DirectMap2M:     1017856 kB


CPU:total 1 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 11, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, aes, erms, tsc

/proc/cpuinfo:
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T7700  @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 11
microcode   : 0x1
cpu MHz     : 3400.022
cache size  : 4096 KB
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx lm constant_tsc up rep_good nopl pni vmx ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes hypervisor lahf_lm fsgsbase smep erms
bogomips    : 6800.04
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:



Memory: 4k page, physical 1027040k(224852k free), swap 0k(0k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.31-b07) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_31-b13), built on Dec 17 2014 20:40:15 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)

time: Fri Feb 27 13:17:50 2015
elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

Comment: Are you really running this _in a virtual machine_ **on a seven year old laptop**?!?

Comment: Its remote vserver

Comment: VPS providers are everywhere. You should not be paying _anything_ for this piece of ... rubbish. A decent 1GB VM on **modern** hardware ought to cost maybe €5 to €7 per month. Go shopping.

Comment: @JakobAbfalter In the meantime you can just decrease the memory used by Play using `/script/to/start-app -mem 500 -Dhttp.port=80 ...`

Comment: thanks for the help, I got it to run somehow again, but I will really consider buying a different VPS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your log sais that when the application is crashing, there is 224852k memory free:

> Memory: 4k page, physical 1027040k(224852k free), swap 0k(0k free)

Also I see that you have no swap partition added. It's obvious that your system starves of memory. So you have to **increase physical memory** or **add swap space**.

To add swap space while the system runs, create a partition, marked as Linux Swap. That the [partition id](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type) 82. Then use that command to set up the partition as a swap area:

```
mkswap /dev/sda4
```

Where `/dev/sda4`, is the device file.

To activate the partition use:

```
swapon /dev/sda4
```

After that you should see `SwapTotal` and `SwapFree` in `/proc/meminfo`.

To make this permanent add a line like this in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda4               swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Can you explain to my how to create sucha partition on an remote server??

Comment: @JakobAbfalter When you have ssh access to it, it is exactly as I described. You have to create a partition for that first. But I don't know your system, so I cannot guide you step-by-step. So, be careful that you don't format/delete needed stuff.

Comment: I got that, but I guess the `You have to create a partition for that first` can`t be done remotely? I have contacted the support, hopefully they can help me out

Comment: I know this question about adding swap is old... You can also add a swap *file* -- this can be useful in cases where repartitioning the disk is difficult or intrusive. Swap file steps are basically, 1) create large file, 2) format file as swap, 3) run `swapon` on the file, 4) add this file to `fstab`. Google it